# Process JSON to create hierarchical relationship of child to parent

Tags: javascript, json, angular, algorithm

I got the similar answer here but I was looking for something opposite of this, so I am taking help from this answer to explain my issue:
[Process JSON to create the hierarchical relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490287/process-json-to-create-the-hierarchical-relationship)

So, I have a raw data something like this:

```
{
  "my_data": [
      {
          "name": "bugs_db",
          "type": "database",
          "children": [
              {
                  "name": "oss",
                  "type": "ui"
              },
              {
                  "name": "dashboard",
                  "type": "ui"
              },
              {
                  "name": "dev-dash",
                  "type": "ui"
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "name": "oss",
          "type": "ui",
          "children": [
              {
                  "name": "active-directory",
                  "type": "nfs"
              },
              {
                  "name": "passive-directory",
                  "type": "FAT32"
              },
              {
                "name": "jira_db",
                "kind": "database"
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "name": "jira_db",
          "type": "database",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "oss",
              "kind": "ui"
            },
            {
              "name": "something",
              "kind": "ui"
            }
          ]
      },
      {
          "name": "active_directory",
          "type": "nfs",
          "children": []
      }
  ]
}
```

I need to process above data to list all the parents for a child.. for exa., if I select "name" = "oss", then the hierarchical relationship should be like this:

```
{
  "name": "oss",
   "type": "ui",
   "parents": [
     {
        "name": "bugs_db",
        "type": "database",
        "parents": [
        ]
     },
     {
       "name": "jira_db",
       "type": "database"
     }
   ]
}
```

Also there can be some circular relationship.. eg. oss child of bugs_db and bugs_db also child of oss.. in such case just skip further and add key "circular": true to the parent object. I think I can try processing using for loops and achieve this.. but I am looking for some similar solution suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50491255

Comment: The fact that your data is stored as json is somewhat irrelevant. All you have to do is create a graph where each vertex is an entry and each edge is a parent-child relationship...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you could use the same scheme which tests for circular reference and filters parents.

```js
function getParents(name, visited = new Set) {
    var item = map.get(name);

    if (!item) {
        return item;
    }

    if (visited.has(name)) {
        return { name, type: item.type, circular: true };
    }

    visited.add(name);

    return {
        name,
        type: item.type,
        parent: object.my_data
            .filter(({ children }) => children.some(o => o.name === name))
            .map(({ name }) => getParents(name, visited))
    };
}

var object = { my_data: [{ name: "bugs_db", type: "database", children: [{ name: "oss", type: "ui" }, { name: "dashboard", type: "ui" }, { name: "dev-dash", type: "ui" }] }, { name: "oss", type: "ui", children: [{ name: "active-directory", type: "nfs" }, { name: "passive-directory", type: "FAT32" }, { name: "jira_db", kind: "database" }] }, { name: "jira_db", type: "database", children: [{ name: "oss", kind: "ui" }, { name: "something", kind: "ui" }] }, { name: "active_directory", type: "nfs", children: [] }] },
    map = new Map(object.my_data.map(o => [o.name, o]));

console.log(getParents("oss"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: wow.. I just saw your profile and saw your answers.. really appreciate your skills...

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem could be solved with an acceptable complexity using loops, if that is the case, as I see in the example, here you have a quite simple solution:

```
function childToParent(obj, child){ 

var newObj = {"name": "","type": "","parents":[]};

  obj.my_data.map((o1,i1)=>{
      o1.children.map((o2,i2)=>{
          if(o2.name == child){            
            newObj.name = o2.name;
            if(o2.type) newObj.type = o2.type;
            newObj.parents.push({"name":o1.name, "type":o1.type});
            if(o1.children) newObj.parents[i2]['parents'] =  o1.children;
          }
      });
  });

  return newObj;

}

console.log(childToParent(obj, "oss"));
```